# In Face the Raven, why does this item get taken?

Tags: doctor-who

In Face the Raven,

> Ashildir takes the Doctor’s confession dial before teleporting him away.

Why? The Doctor already had

> the teleporter on his wrist, which means he would go to the torture hell anyway.

Or was it that the

> confession dial needed to be manipulated to be converted to a torture chamber before the Doctor was teleported?

Comment: It might be a bit weird to teleport someone into something that they’re carrying in their pocket.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite And since when was Doctor Who not "a bit weird"? :-)

Comment: I think the first comment by @Paul is the answer. If the Confession Dial wasn't taken, maybe the teleportation wouldn't work because something can't teleport inside itself.

Comment: Thank you for putting the episode in the title so I could avoid the spoilers (I know I clicked on it to comment, but I didn't read the question, so as not to see the spoilers etc. lol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final speculation is correct.

In "Hell Bent", The Doctor gets very angry about what happened to him after "Face the Raven". In particular, he says that:

> the confession dial was never meant to be used the way his was used -- to basically torture and interrogate a living Time Lord.

We can infer from this that The Doctor would never have set up his confession dial to act this way, so the people who made the deal with Ashildir must have done so. They would have needed access to it to do that, so they had Ashildir take it before he teleported.

Comment: But, there wasn't any time to do the manipulation.

Comment: Maybe the "program" so to speak, was already written, and could have been uploaded to the device very quickly once it was taken...would have to re-watch to see the sequence of events though

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433  They're Time Lords. They have all the time they need. Just teleport The Doctor a year into the future and you have an entire year to reprogram it.

Comment: The Doctor said: He could sense the time travel and he wasn't teleported into the future. That's how he was able to calculate the years by seeing the stars in the first place.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: he also said he’d gone no more than a light year from where he was, yet when he came out of the confession dial he ended up on Gallifrey. Maybe Gallifrey is that close in space to earth (or will be by the end of the universe), but like Mike said, Time Lords. I’m guessing the Confession Dial is Time Lord technology, so it’s not inconceivable that they would be prepared to reconfigure it instantly upon coming into possession of it.

Comment: @Paul Unable to understand what you really want to say...

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: focus on this bit: I’m guessing the Confession Dial is Time Lord technology, so it’s conceivable that they would be prepared to reconfigure it instantly upon coming into possession of it.

Comment: @Paul Again, there was no time. The Doctor was teleported inside the Confession Dial which was within one light year (the same room) and same time zone (instantly because Doctor can feel time travel and he didn't travel in time).

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: “Again, there was no time.” Please direct your attention [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instantly).

Comment: @Paul Haha.. Yeah, it's possible. They applied some kind of template instantly...

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: or it was done in the interval between the Doctor giving the dial to Ashildur, and being teleported. That wasn’t a long time, but maybe it doesn’t take long.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Teleportation involves your body being destroyed and reconstructed somewhere else. The doctor's body could have been reconstructed in the confession dial long after we see him disappear. After all, he can't feel that kind of time travel (his body is repeatedly reconstructed millions/billions of years after he was actually teleported and he never feels time travel).

Comment: It could simply be that the Time Lords, with a newer, more modern, not broken TARDIS than the Doctor's Model 40, were able to get the confession dial, time travel back a few days/months/years (as necessary), reprogram the confession dial for their nefarious needs, then very accurately travel back to milliseconds after the Doctor handed it to Ashildir so it was there to receive the teleporting Doctor. I mean, they are Time Lords, "time" is a very relative measure to them.